# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_encrypt

Tags: php, mcrypt

```
       $key = '6yOFZuQis%7$oF_[M89=EV!a}\mzb7=B';
       $iv = 'Fa)=zx"h^O8t.-s4nO-q#vTp,,ft;fCj';

       $data = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, serialize($data), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
       $data=base64_encode($data);
```

above code works in localhost without any errors with encrypted value.but while uploading   line number 3 
($data=mcrypt) shows error as

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_encrypt() in demo.php on line 3.....
>   i cant understand what is the error.I googled about it but i didnt get answer.

Comment: Protip: **Read the error message**.  Does it say anything about base64?  Nope, it's complaining about [`mcrypt_encrypt`](http://php.net/mcrypt_encrypt) being missing.

Answer (score 3):

Check this with your host if PHP mcrypt library is installed or not. If you have root access to your server, run the following command:

yum install php-mcrypt